# JSON from .NEt WCF to JavaScript array of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, jqplot

I'm using jqPlot and I need to turn this JSON which I receive from a WCF service:

```
[{ "x": 2, "y": 3 }, { "x": 25, "y": 34 }]
```

into this array or arrays:

```
[[2,3],[25,34]]
```

I've tried JSON.parse & eval but to no avail.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to do that:

```
var data = [{ "x": 2, "y": 3 }, { "x": 25, "y": 34 }]

var flattenedResult = $.map(data, function(point) {
  return [[ point.x, point.y ]];
});
```

Comment: The `map` method flattens the result, so `flattenedResult` will contain `[2,3,25,34]`, not `[[2,3],[25,34]]`. Also, you forgot the step of parsing the JSON.

Comment: Wow Mr. Encosia answered my question. This must be how normal people feel when they meet a celebrity...

Comment: @Guffa: You're right.  Wrapping the return array in a second array literal defeats the flattening though.  If he's requesting it with jQuery, the JSON should already parsed by the time he gets it, so no need for that.

Comment: @Jamie: I'm definitely sure that I'm nothing like a celebrity.

Comment: @Dave Ward: Wrapping the return array in a second array would give the result `[[2,3,25,34]]`, not `[[2,3],[25,34]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the string into an array of objects:

```
var json = '[{ "x": 2, "y": 3 }, { "x": 25, "y": 34 }]';
var o = $.parseJSON(json);
```

Then replace each object in the array with an array:

```
for (var i=0; i<o.length; i++) o[i] = [o[i].x, o[i].y];
```

Comment: This actually work's very nicely, whereas the other answers result in a flattened array.

Comment: @Jamie Carruthers: Yes, I tested the code before posting it. :) I first tried the `map` method, but as I noticed that it flattens the result I went with a regular loop instead.