# jquery ajax remote call IEnumerable

Tags: wcf, ienumerable

I have traversed the web and have found numerous examples on how to retrieve single data objects coming back from a remote .Net service WCF or ASMX), but how would I perform a jQuery ajax call bringing back a list of Person objects, lets says IEnumerable?

The whole idea would be to bring this data back and set it as a datasource for a grid.

This is a WebForms project.

Any short conside code snippet or link would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a method List GetPersons() which returns a list of Person object, that will be translated to an array in your service response (SOAP/JSON).
Or the other option to have a cleaner array is List GetPersons().

Here is a link related to jquery WCF JSON arrays: [JSON from .NEt WCF to JavaScript array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238677/json-from-net-wcf-to-javascript-array-of-arrays)